# Execute Change event only if element has a specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to do some calculations only if the radio button has the attribute `data-price`. Currently the calculation is executed all the time for all the radio buttons.

I Have attached My Code. Can any one help me on this?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
 <title>Hotel Beds</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"
 ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {
        var values = {};
        $('input:radio').change(function() {
            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            values[name] = parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
            var total = 0.0;
            $.each(values, function(i, e) {
                total += e;
            });
            $('#total').text(total.toFixed(2));
        });
    });             
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="t1" data-price="25" checked="checked" />
        <span>Price 25</span>
        <input type="radio" name="t1" data-price="30" />
        <span>Price 30</span>
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="t2" data-price="40" />
        <span>Price 40</span>
        <input type="radio" name="t2" data-price="50" />
        <span>Price 50</span>
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="G" /><span>Male</span>
        <input type="radio" name="G" /><span>Female</span>
        <input id="total" type="text" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to do some calculation if the radio button has data price attribute.

You can use the ["has attribute" selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) to limit the selection to just the radio buttons with that attribute:

```
$('input:radio[data-price]').change(...
```

---

Side note: Using jQuery's CSS extensions is not best practice, because [as it says in the `:radio` API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/), it means jQuery can't hand off to the browser's native handling. Instead:

```
$('input[type=radio][data-price]').change(...
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to change one think to add the total.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var values = {};
    $('input:radio[data-price]').change(function (){

          var name = $(this).attr('name');
          values[name] = parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
          var total = 0.0;
          $.each(values, function (i, e) {
            total += e;
            console.log('total', total);
          });
          $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2)); // val(total) instead of text(total)
    }); 
});
```

Please see the [working demo at plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/esT3Eacq2yAwEP4afR6t?p=preview)